# Are metadata duplicated in Hive tables stored as ORC?

Tags: hive, orc

Being ORC a self-descriptive format, informations about columns are stored within the files.

When a new table is created and stored as ORC, its metadata are added to the Hive matastore.

Aren't these informations duplicated? How does Hive handle this?

Answer (score 0):

A possible explanation:
The columns metadata (COLUMN_NAME, TYPE_NAME, COMMENT etc) is reflected in only a single table in the hive metastore (COLUMNS_V2).
The hive metastore is consisted of dozens of tables with various dependencies.
So having the columns metadata  removed from the metastore may save a small duplicity, but it is negligible in comparison to the entire metastore db (in our cluster its a 176KB/530MB ratio).
I guess that saving ~0.01% of redundancy isn't worth the hassle of redesigning the metastore schema.

ORC is a format that is compatible with many other technologies other then Hive.
Could be that hive is using only the columnar compression, while ignoring the benefit of self describing data format.

Comment: Yes, it could be. Anyway, we got in troubles when we tried to alter a column type for a table stored as ORC (from char(8) to varchar(8)).
It does not complain at alter time, but it throws an exception when data is queried, telling something about types mismatch.